# How to set visibility on view layers via python?

Tags: python, visibility, viewlayers

What was obj.hide in Blender 2.79 is now obj.hide_viewport in 2.80.

This is different from the newly introduced visibility on view layers, which describes visibility on different viewlayers, and is what the default show/hide ops or the eye icons in the outliner describe.

Using obj.visible_get() you can return the the visibility state on the active view layer.

There is no visible_set() method, as far as I can tell.  So how can you set the visibility on the active or other view layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, it's `obj.hide_set(True)`, has been introduces 2 months ago or so, I think.