# EEVEE 2.80 toggling render visibility based on camera view

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, optimization, visibility

I suspect this is possible, but don’t know where to start. I think drivers might be the key. I want to animate EEVEE render visibility of 24 objects off when the object leaves the camera FOV and on the frame before it comes back into camera FOV. The reason I want to do this is to omit Principled BSDF calculation of materials, bounces etc when objects are outside the frame to shorten render time. NB: everything is inside a Torus if that factors into the answer. Thank you Blender geniuses!

Comment: Have a read of [Eevee limitations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/limitations.html).  I don't know how much gain there is to be had.  Have you tested the performance gain?

Answer (score 1):

For EEVEE is useless, because all effects like reflections, AO, etc are rendered in screen space, no object that left camera frustum is calculated at all. For Cycles this option called "Camera Culling", and located in Simplify settings:

[image]

And in Object properties:

[image]

Comment: related reading material: [How does Eevee work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120372/how-does-eevee-work/120378#120378) and [cycles vs eevee](https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it automatically but you can do it manually. Just toggle the render visibility icon (looks like a camera) in the outliner on and off then press "i" while hovering over the icon. It will add a keyframe. Forgot to add, you may have to turn on the icon in the latest 2.8 builds with the drop down menu in the outliner that looks kind of like a triangle.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I found this too: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122578/how-to-set-visibility-on-view-layers-via-python?rq=1